# how to call function in parent component

Tags: reactjs

There's a fiddle for this question [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4TpnG/504/)I have a FormControl component in a React.js app in which I render several different types of other components. For example, in the code below, you can see that I render a CheckBoxWithLabel. You will notice that I pass an a function

```
onCheck={this.toggleCheckBox}
```

so that in the CheckBoxWithLabel component (code not shown) I can call it with the onChange event (a built in event for checkboxes in react)

```
onChange={this.props.onCheck} //this code's in the CheckBoxWithLabel
```

So the result is that when the checkbox is clicked, the `toggleCheckBox` function in the parent component is called, but this is only working for the first `CheckBoxWithLabel` shown below, the others (which are dynamically created in the second return function) are not able to be checked, and hence the toggleCheckBox function is not getting called.

Why is that?

If instead of trying to call a function on the parent, I had those components respond with a function in the CheckBoxWithLabel component, then they work fine. It's only when I set a function in the parent that the checkboxes stop working and the toggleCheckBox function's not called.

```
 toggleCheckBox: function(){
   console.log('toggle');
 }
 render: function(){
        return (  

          <div>
          <CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" item='blah' onCheck={this.toggleCheckBox} />
          <ul>
            {
            this.props.formElements.map(function(item) {

            return <CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" item={item} onCheck={this.toggleCheckBox} />

            })
            }               
        </ul>
          </div>
          );
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function inside of map needs to be bound so that it can use the correct instance of `this` to retrieve the function:

```
render: function(){
  return (  
    <div>
      <CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" item='blah' onCheck={this.toggleCheckBox} />
      <ul>
      {
        this.props.formElements.map(function(item) {
          return <CheckboxWithLabel labelOn="On" labelOff="Off" item={item} onCheck={this.toggleCheckBox} />
        }.bind(this));
      }               
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought react handled bind for you (that was a console message from react I received at one point). Anyways, I find it interesting that you put the bind statement where you did. Don't really understand why you put it there ratehr than on the end of the `toggleCheckBox` function, but it works. Thanks